# Retrieves a list of apps that results of searching by the given term on app store or iTunes store

Tags: ios, node.js, web-scraping, app-store, itunes-store

I am using Node.js module to scrape application data from the iTunes/Mac App Store. My purpose is find then app ranking in search result for particular keyword search.

> https://github.com/facundoolano/app-store-scraper

Till today, This module was giving proper app ranking on search results by keyword but suddenly It completely shows different search result than app store in iPhone or Mac.

Does anyone know that There are any changes from apple side?

Module uses below apple url to find the search result.

```
const BASE_URL = 'https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/search?clientApplication=Software&media=software&term=';
```

Does any changes in above URL?

Comment: Which app and market are you talking about?
I just tried to pull the last version of the code and the search result looks correct to me
https://repl.it/repls/SecretHightechDeletion

Answer (score 2):

Here is the official api documentation for itunes search api - https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/

Here is an example below for the search you are trying to do:

```
curl -X GET \
  'https://itunes.apple.com/search?clientApplication=Software&media=software&term=Misfits%20Emoji' \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Host: itunes.apple.com' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 06880666-0bb8-4b43-80ed-53e4300444cd,004c0b3c-dffd-4b3d-90e3-e36167e2a127' \
  -H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.20.1' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```

For the example, I have used this application to search https://apps.apple.com/us/app/misfits-emoji/id1172889389 and it is the first item returned in the response.

Response:

```
{
    "resultCount": 1,
    "results": [{
        "artistViewUrl": "https://apps.apple.com/us/developer/fan-si-inc/id932552952?uo=4",
        "artworkUrl60": "https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple71/v4/f5/ac/81/f5ac813b-2c60-5739-023d-fca28a4b5fb5/source/60x60bb.jpg",
        "artworkUrl100": "https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple71/v4/f5/ac/81/f5ac813b-2c60-5739-023d-fca28a4b5fb5/source/100x100bb.jpg",
        "screenshotUrls": ["https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple71/v4/95/8b/4c/958b4c46-b4d8-f035-d723-ef764131a1f9/pr_source.png/392x696bb.png", "https://is3-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple71/v4/ab/c0/a2/abc0a2f7-30c3-6f4f-2fa9-f2ccf4b15912/pr_source.png/392x696bb.png"],
        "ipadScreenshotUrls": [],
        "appletvScreenshotUrls": [],
        "artworkUrl512": "https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple71/v4/f5/ac/81/f5ac813b-2c60-5739-023d-fca28a4b5fb5/source/512x512bb.jpg",
        "isGameCenterEnabled": false,
        "advisories": [],
        "supportedDevices": ["iPad2Wifi-iPad2Wifi", "iPad23G-iPad23G", "iPhone4S-iPhone4S", "iPadThirdGen-iPadThirdGen", "iPadThirdGen4G-iPadThirdGen4G", "iPhone5-iPhone5", "iPodTouchFifthGen-iPodTouchFifthGen", "iPadFourthGen-iPadFourthGen", "iPadFourthGen4G-iPadFourthGen4G", "iPadMini-iPadMini", "iPadMini4G-iPadMini4G", "iPhone5c-iPhone5c", "iPhone5s-iPhone5s", "iPadAir-iPadAir", "iPadAirCellular-iPadAirCellular", "iPadMiniRetina-iPadMiniRetina", "iPadMiniRetinaCellular-iPadMiniRetinaCellular", "iPhone6-iPhone6", "iPhone6Plus-iPhone6Plus", "iPadAir2-iPadAir2", "iPadAir2Cellular-iPadAir2Cellular", "iPadMini3-iPadMini3", "iPadMini3Cellular-iPadMini3Cellular", "iPodTouchSixthGen-iPodTouchSixthGen", "iPhone6s-iPhone6s", "iPhone6sPlus-iPhone6sPlus", "iPadMini4-iPadMini4", "iPadMini4Cellular-iPadMini4Cellular", "iPadPro-iPadPro", "iPadProCellular-iPadProCellular", "iPadPro97-iPadPro97", "iPadPro97Cellular-iPadPro97Cellular", "iPhoneSE-iPhoneSE", "iPhone7-iPhone7", "iPhone7Plus-iPhone7Plus", "iPad611-iPad611", "iPad612-iPad612", "iPad71-iPad71", "iPad72-iPad72", "iPad73-iPad73", "iPad74-iPad74", "iPhone8-iPhone8", "iPhone8Plus-iPhone8Plus", "iPhoneX-iPhoneX", "iPad75-iPad75", "iPad76-iPad76", "iPhoneXS-iPhoneXS", "iPhoneXSMax-iPhoneXSMax", "iPhoneXR-iPhoneXR", "iPad812-iPad812", "iPad834-iPad834", "iPad856-iPad856", "iPad878-iPad878", "iPadMini5-iPadMini5", "iPadMini5Cellular-iPadMini5Cellular", "iPadAir3-iPadAir3", "iPadAir3Cellular-iPadAir3Cellular", "iPodTouchSeventhGen-iPodTouchSeventhGen", "iPhone11-iPhone11", "iPhone11Pro-iPhone11Pro", "iPadSeventhGen-iPadSeventhGen", "iPadSeventhGenCellular-iPadSeventhGenCellular", "iPhone11ProMax-iPhone11ProMax"],
        "kind": "software",
        "features": [],
        "contentAdvisoryRating": "4+",
        "trackCensoredName": "Misfits Emoji",
        "languageCodesISO2A": ["EN"],
        "fileSizeBytes": "32731136",
        "sellerUrl": "http://fan.si",
        "averageUserRatingForCurrentVersion": 3.5,
        "userRatingCountForCurrentVersion": 4,
        "trackViewUrl": "https://apps.apple.com/us/app/misfits-emoji/id1172889389?uo=4",
        "trackContentRating": "4+",
        "currentVersionReleaseDate": "2016-11-21T17:30:21Z",
        "releaseNotes": "Updated icons.",
        "isVppDeviceBasedLicensingEnabled": true,
        "formattedPrice": "$0.99",
        "trackId": 1172889389,
        "trackName": "Misfits Emoji",
        "primaryGenreName": "Entertainment",
        "genreIds": ["6016", "6002"],
        "primaryGenreId": 6016,
        "sellerName": "Fansi Inc",
        "releaseDate": "2016-11-17T18:12:35Z",
        "minimumOsVersion": "8.0",
        "currency": "USD",
        "version": "1.0.1",
        "wrapperType": "software",
        "artistId": 932552952,
        "artistName": "Fan.si Inc.",
        "genres": ["Entertainment", "Utilities"],
        "price": 0.99,
        "description": "Social Club Misfits present this very rare emoji collection featuring dozens of new emoticon pictures and exclusive gifs. Satisfy all you communication needs with pizza, pugs, pineapples, and so much more!",
        "bundleId": "si.fan.socialmisfits-emoji"
    }]
}
```